# How to write Graham Algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to write Graham algorithm (convex hull) in Python. I have some function generating random points:

```
def generatePoints(n):
    global pointsList
    for x in range(0, n):
        rPoint = Point(random.randint(-10, 10), random.randint(-10, 10))
        if(rPoint not in pointsList):
            pointsList.append(rPoint)
```

then I have a function which finds the point with lowest Y value:

```
def findStartingPoint():
    global startingPoint
    global pointsList
    for pt in pointsList:
        if(pt.y < startingPoint.y):
            startingPoint = pt
        elif(pt.y == startingPoint.y):
            if(pt.x < startingPoint.x):
                startingPoint = pt
    for pt in pointsList:
        if(startingPoint == pt):
            pointsList.remove(pt)
```

another function sorts the list of points (excluding startingPoint) for alpha (angle according to startingPoint) and if both has same alpha it also sorts for X value of the point. It also moves all the points for (0,0) -> startingPoint vector before sort and moves them back to their previous state after sort:

```
def sortPoints():
    global startingPoint
    global pointsList
    moveX = startingPoint.x
    moveY = startingPoint.y
    for pt in pointsList:
        pt.x = pt.x - moveX
        pt.y = pt.y - moveY
        d = math.fabs(pt.x) + math.fabs(pt.y) 
        if(pt.x >= 0 and pt.y >= 0):
            pt.alfa = pt.y / d
        elif(pt.x < 0 and pt.y >= 0):
            pt.alfa = 2 - (pt.y / d)
        elif(pt.x < 0 and pt.y < 0):
            pt.alfa = 2 + (math.fabs(pt.y) / d)
        elif(pt.x >= 0 and pt.y < 0):
            pt.alfa = 4 - (math.fabs(pt.y) / d)
    pointsList = sorted(pointsList, key=attrgetter('alfa', 'x'))
    for pt in pointsList:
        pt.x = pt.x + moveX
        pt.y = pt.y + moveY
```

So now I have startingPoint and sorted list of points. I also have a function checking whether next point is on the right or on the left of the line which connects 2 previous points (as the algorithm says):

```
def isRight(p1, p2, p3):
    vecA = [(p2.x - p1.x), (p2.y - p1.y)]
    print "vecA: " +  str(vecA[0]) + " " + str(vecA[1])
    vecB = [(p3.x - p1.x), (p3.y - p1.y)]
    print "vecB: " +  str(vecB[0]) + " " + str(vecB[1])
    ilo = vecA[0] * vecB[1] - vecA[1] * vecB[0]
    if(ilo > 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here comes the problem. My algorithm function looks like this:

```
def graham():
    global pointsStack
    global pointsList
    pointsStack.push(0)
    pointsStack.push(1)
    pointsStack.push(2)
    for i in range(3, len(pointsList)):
        while isRight(pointsList[i-2], pointsList[i-1], pointsList[i]):
            pointsStack.pop()
        pointsStack.push(i)
```

It just goes for "stack is empty exception" (sometimes it works for 1-for iteration). What is wrong with my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `while` loop:

```
while isRight(pointsList[i-2], pointsList[i-1], pointsList[i]):
    pointsStack.pop()
```

Since you don't increment the `i`, it will repeat popping from the stack until it is empty (and beyond).

You made a semantical error. It's not the `pointLists` that must provide the first two points, but the stack. As a result each time you need to `pop` one element from the stack (keep it in memory), `peek` the stack for the first point, the second is the element just popped from the stack and the last is the `pointList[i]`'th one. In case your stack is implemented as a list, you can thus use:

```
while isRight(pointsList[pointsStack[-2]], pointsList[pointsStack[-1]], pointsList[i]):
        pointsStack.pop()
```

A final aspect is that you need to add the offset point to the `pointList` as well as the last point so that when you return, you can optionally remove the point with the largest alpha.

You can also optimize your sorting function by using the `isRight` function on the points with the offset point as `p1`.